# Why does Vim highlight every dot in my code?

Tags: vimrc, highlight

I program with Python and I installed [python-mode](https://github.com/klen/python-mode#using-pathogen-recommended) with pathogen. Everything was fine but then suddenly Vim started highlighting all the dots in the files. And it's kind of frustrating.

I thought it was the plug-in so I deleted everything in my `~/.vimrc`. The content on my `~/.vimrc` was:

```
" Pathogen load
filetype off

call pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#helptags()

filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

But nope, it wasn't the plugin: Vim still highlights all the dots. I'll attach an image.

Can you give me a hand with this? I'll appreciate it big time, promise.

[image: vim highlights dots]

Comment: Is your `'hlsearch'` option set? Find out by typing `:set hlsearch?` in normal mode.

Comment: jjaderberg might be on the good track: it seems that Vim is highligting matches of the last pattern you searched for. If you make a new search with `/new pattern` dots will probably not be highligted anymore. In the doc [`:h hlsearch`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27hlsearch%27) you can read "When there is a previous search pattern, highlight all its matches" then if `:set hlsearch?` outputs `hlsearch` you can use `set hlsearch!` to disable it.

Comment: Another way for removing the highlight is setting the `last search register` to empty `:let @/ = ""` but it will clear your last search not only disable the highlighting. I have this mapping on my `.vimrc` `nnoremap <silent><leader>cs :let @/ = ""<cr>`

Comment: @jjaderberg  @statox Thank you all for your comments and support! I've learned a lot since I post this question yesterday! Now I have rules on my `.vimrc` about the highlighting. It was indeed `hlsearch`. It's funny how something like a search can drive you crazy. @vappolinario I'll try your suggestion too! thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [jjaderberg](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/1306/jjaderberg) and [statox](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/1841/statox) have mentioned it seems like you have set `hlsearch`. All `.` in your file will be highlighted when you search for them directly (`/.`) or if your cursor is placed on a dot and you press `*`. The highlighting stays enabled till you either:

- Perform a new search with `/{something}`
- Perform a new search for the word under your cursor with `*`
- Disable the current highlighting with `:nohlsearch`, or short `:noh`. This leaves search highlighting on in general for your next search.
- Disable search highlighting completely with `:set nohlsearch`, or short `:set nohl`. This disables search highlighting for your next searches. If you want this to be a permanent state, add it to your `.vimrc`.

Comment: I added `set nohlsearch` to my `.vimrc` and worked like a charm. I did this because I have updated several files since the `.` appeared highlighted and doing `set nohlsearch` just turn off the highlighting in the current file. Thank you for the solution and the explanation.

Comment: (I wonder if it's customary (good practice?) to wait for the OP author to confirm the issue (already) raised in the comments and give a chance to one of those authors to place their answers.)

Comment: Thank you for that hint, you are right. Sorry @jjaderberg and @statox. As you can tell I tried to give credit by linking their name in my answer. I wanted to mention the `:noh` command which was not mentioned before, but was unable to do so in a comment cause I had too little reputation.

Comment: VanLaser is right I don't know if it is written somewhere but it is a part of the etiquette to let people who made useful comments to make their answers once the OP confirmed the problem is solved. The period without comments ends quickly if you make some good posts so no need to create an answer to add something which should have been a comment. No hard feeling for this time but remember to put respect before point hunting ;-)

Comment: It's not too late for those who commented but didn't post an answer to do so.   I can't speak for everywhere but I'm more likely to upvote people who've commented and then posted, over the glory boys!  Have faith in the system to work.

Comment: As he seems new, I just hope @cbaumhardt is not put off by this (I was just giving a friendly suggestion).

Comment: No worries, I am not. I took your advice as the tip you meant to give and I appreciate it :)

Comment: In my .vimrc, I've got a mapping: `nnoremap <silent> <leader>/ :nohlsearch<CR>`. Since I've also set `mapleader` to comma, a simple `,/` will clear the search highlight for the current window, without disabling it altogether. Handy if you like to have search highlighting when you actually are searching, but want it gone once you're finished.

Comment: [tpope's vim-sensible plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sensible/blob/master/plugin/sensible.vim#L31) includes a mapping for this as well: `<C-L>`. That's what I use cause I also don't want to disable it altogether.